# Linux scripting last user added

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to Linux Scripting and got stuck with this exercise.
I need to find out if the current user is the last added user. 
If not then I need to show the last added user.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash --

lastUser ='tail -1 /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1'

if [[ $lastUser -ne $USER ]]; then
      echo "I am $USER and I am not the last added user."
      echo "The last added user is $lastUser."
else
      echo "I am $USER and I am the last added user."
fi
```

The error I get: `line 3: lastUser: command not found.`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I don't believe there is any guarantee that the last entry in `/etc/passwd` is necessarily the last one added...

Comment: is there another way to find it easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
lastUser=$(tail -1 /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1)

if [ "$lastUser" != "$USER" ]; then
    echo "I am $USER and I am not the last added user."
    echo "The last added user is $lastUser."
else
    echo "I am $USER and I am the last added user."
fi
```

`lastUser` is a string in the code you provided, it's not executing the cmd .
Also, do not forget to not put spaces around the `=`

Comment: Oh I get it, but -ne in the if doesn't work. If I use !=, then it works. Thx!

Comment: Care, *The last added user is the user who hold the biggest UID* and `/etc/passwd` is not necessarly sorted! Have a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27986051/1765658)

Comment: @F.Hauri "The last added user is the user who hold the biggest UID", not sure about that, on my system the last line is the latest user added. I've a UID greater than him and i'm not the latest user added.

Comment: @Hacketo You'r right: UID is not right way, but try: `sudo pwck -s`!